# When Update AngularJs ui-mask, ui-mask-placeholder the ng-model is not updated

Tags: angularjs

I have the following input in my view

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="registerCardNumber" name="registerCardNumber" ng-model="vm.cardNumber" ui-mask="{{vm.cardMask}}" ui-mask-placeholder="{{vm.cardMaskPlaceholder}}" ng-keyup="vm.events.replaceMasks()" required>
```

I want to check in my controller, according to the first digit added the card type, since there are cards that should have a different mask (AmEx).

Here is my controller code

```
var defaultCardMask = "9999 - 9999 - 9999 - 9999";
var defaultCardMaskPlaceholder = "XXXX - XXXX - XXXX - XXXX";
var americanExpressCardMask = "9999 - 999999 - 99999";
var americanExpressCardMaskPlaceholder = "XXXX - XXXXXX - XXXXX";

        function replaceMasks()
        {
            //3 digits on the back of the card for Visa, Mastercard and Discover Card
            //3 or 4 digits on the front of the card for American Express Card

            //cannot use model since it is not valid yet (does is not according to the mask)
            var cardNumber = $("#registerCardNumber").val();
            if (cardNumber.indexOf('X') != 1) return;
            var firstCardNumberDigit = cardNumber.charAt(0);
            if (getCardNumberDigits(firstCardNumberDigit) == 15)
            {
                vm.cardMask = americanExpressCardMask;
                vm.cardMaskPlaceholder = americanExpressCardMaskPlaceholder;
                vm.cardNumber = firstCardNumberDigit + americanExpressCardMaskPlaceholder.substring(1);
                $("#registerCardNumber").val(firstCardNumberDigit + americanExpressCardMaskPlaceholder.substring(1));
            }
            else {
                vm.cardMask = defaultCardMask;
                vm.cardMaskPlaceholder = defaultCardMaskPlaceholder;
                vm.cardNumber = firstCardNumberDigit + defaultCardMaskPlaceholder.substring(1);
            }
        }

        function getCardNumberDigits(firstCardNumberDigit)
        {
            //3 are always American Express (AmEx) -> 15
            //4 are always Visa -> 16
            //5 are always Mastercard -> 16
            //6 are always Discover Card -> 15

            if (firstCardNumberDigit == 3 || firstCardNumberDigit == 6)
                return 15;
            return 16;
        }
```

When debugging,  $("#registerCardNumber").val(..); changes the input data correctly, afterwards, the input value is set to mask's value.

How can i fix this? Thanks